# How to Tortoise to move repository without losing history

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a repository on my PC. Now I want to move some project to a online svn server. This server doesn't provide ftp access, so I couldn't copy svn folder there....
Does anybody know how to move my project there without losing history.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html)** is an awesome way to do this. It lets you replay all the commits from one repo to another. What you're really doing here is mirroring. Once you're done with the sync, you can disable it and cutover to the new repo.

Or keep both--one as a backup!

If you can get a file up there somehow, the regular [backup/restore](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Subversion_backup_and_restore#Subversion_backup_and_restore) process works well, too, and is fast.